# Flutter connection back online background event listener

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity

I've been trying to learn Flutter by developing an Offline-first application using non-firebase backend API. The problem I am trying to solve derives from the following requirements:

- Given User devise is Offline and he creates a record in the app, the record is stored on a local Database and is synced to backend once app is back online
- If the app is not in the foreground, user should receive notifications once he is back online, given something changed on BE while he was offline.

Now, the problem is that reading through some packages that Flutter provides like [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch), I've stumbled upon the following limitation: "Background Fetch is a very simple plugin which will awaken an app in the background about every **15 minutes**, providing a short period of background running-time."
The problem is that testing a similar IOS offline-first app I've noticed that notification comes through **the moment** internet is back online.

My question is the following: How can I achieve an immediate response/notification from my Flutter app once internet is back online, given that application is not working in the foreground. A fetch once every 15 minutes would work but is obviously is less than ideal, and given there are already apps on App Store/Play market that are notifying me immediately just keeps me awake at night. Is there a way to configure an event listener for connectivity change without relying on the 15 min limitation?